# Apache - Redirecting from one URL to another with a new domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'd like to redirect a list of URLs to another list in a new domain, like this:

```
myoldsite.com/page1 => mynewsite.com/the-new-page-1
```

The base of my `.htaccess` file is likek this

```
Redirect 301 /v2/test https://newdomain.com/foo
Redirect 301 /v2/hello https://newdomain.com/bar
```

But when I access `http://myoldsite.com/v2/test` I don't get redirected to `https://newdomain.com/foo`. FYI the source site has a `.htaccess` on /v2 folder.

Answer (score 0):

If your `.htaccess` file is inside the `v2` folder already, then you don't need the `/v2/` part and the redirects should be something like this:

```
Redirect 301 test https://newdomain.com/foo
Redirect 301 hello https://newdomain.com/bar
```

Answer (score 0):

if the .htaccess file is in the folder ./v2/ you should omit "/v2" from your rewrite rule

or you move the rules to a .htaccess file in the document root